# How to make a square polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis

I need a square polygon to clip layers to, in QGIS, a perfect square perhaps.
It needs to be a certain size. Anyone have any experience or any good ideas?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116302/create-polygons-and-fishnets-of-specific-size-and-orientation-and-buffers

Comment: Not sure what version this came out in but you may use the "CAD-like improved polygon capture" tool on the main editing toolbar.  This will allow you to manually define each segment length to create a square.

Comment: Look here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94728/drawing-tools-to-add-circles-arrows-lines-for-qgis

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I did an hour or two of research, but time constraints meant I had less than a couple of hours to find the right tool as it needed to be discovered and installed and was not obvious from using help in QGIS. Anyhow there is a new answer so perhaps the collective state of GIS knowledge has advanced somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom CRS around the center of the desired square:

> ```
> +proj=tmerc +lon_0=7 +lat_0=51 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
> ```

2. Create a textfile with the following content for a 10*10 km square:

> ```
> Geom,
> "POLYGON((-5000 -5000, -5000 5000, 5000 5000, 5000 -5000, -5000 -5000))"
> ```

3. Add the file as `delimited text`
4. Save the layer as a shapefile for further processing and delete the delimited text layer
5. Densify the geometry with `Vector -> Geometry tools -> Densify Geometries ...`
6. Save the layer to the CRS of the layer you want to clip

Comment: Thanks, great answer, more firepower than I needed though. I'm sure another user will find it valuable, would make a great extension ; )